# Using a calculated value in subsequent formula(s)

Tags: proc-sql

To be more efficient, I want to calculate the total of a field (e.g., `TOTALFIELDA`) and then use just the resulting total amount in subsequent calculations (not to have the total amount appear for every record in the table).

Using this approach I receive an error message that the field `TOTALFIELDA` is not valid.

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT
SUM(fieldA) AS TOTALFIELDA,
Sum(fieldX)/TOTALFIELDA AS TOTALXPERFIELDA,
FROM TABLE1;
```

I don't want the value of `TOTALFIELDA` to be populated for all records in the table.  If the result of summing `fieldA` is 100, and the result of `sum(fieldx)` is `150` then I just want the result of `(150/100)` or `1.5`.
I don't believe PROC SQL has `CROSS APPLY` or CTE equivalents.

Comment: What's wrong with the usual way of doing this with `SUM(fieldX)/SUM(fieldA) AS TOTALFIELDA`?

Comment: I get this ERROR message: "Summary functions nested in this way are not supported"

Comment: There were some fields I was calculating that solely use alias' from other calculated fields in the formula; for example:  (CALCULATED FIELD1 + CALCULATED FIELD2) AS NEWFIELD1

When I comment out those fields, I get the error "ERROR: Summary functions nested in this way are not supported" for the following calculated fields feeding the formula; for example:

((SUM(fieldA) / sum(fieldB))*100) AS FIELD1,
(SUM(fieldB) / sum(fieldB) + sum(fieldC)) AS FIELD2

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add details instead of burying them in comments. Posting sample data and the output you're expecting from that data would be helpful.